# Customising a Facebook page - Page App vs. External app with iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

Trying to decide between creating a Page App vs. iFrame (Load a hosted page somewhere else like AWS or APP Engine)

I am trying to create a 'tab' on a Facebook page where users can upload pictures to that page for a contest app.

I would like to create some customisation for this contest page.
Hence not using popular off the shelf contest providers like wishpond etx.

The user should be able to view his uploaded pictures on the top layout of the screen while the latest uploads of other users (trending, most liked) can get displayed at the remaining mid, bottom section of the page.

To attain this feature of custom layouting a page, would you recommend creating a 'page app' or create a Javascript based HTML page and host it outside on 'external web server' and render in an iFrame app within my tab ?

If it can be done both ways, would like to hear some adv/disadvantages of each approach.

Hope it explains. 
Let me know if I was not clear.

Thanks,
Srik

Comment: "Page App vs. iFrame"? page apps run in an iframe.

Comment: Page tab apps _are_ hosted outside of Facebook, and embedded via an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

What´s better is opinionated, but here are the main differences between a Page App (that runs in an iframe on a Facebook Page) and an external Website:

- Page Apps don´t work on mobile, so you have to share an external link, check for mobile and keep mobile users on the external link while redirecting desktop users to the Page App.
- Page apps are restricted to a width of 810px.